# Arithmetic Lattices in Vector Spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

In the literature one often sees references to discrete subgroups of semi-simple algebraic and Lie groups which are arithmetic lattices.

One can also define a lattice in a real vector space , is it possible to have an analogous concept of an arithmetic lattice in a vector space?

Comment: Sure, just follow the same prescription as for any real Lie group. But _every_ lattice in a (finite-dimensional) real vector space is "arithmetic" by any of the usual definitions, so nothing particularly interesting happens...

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by a lattice in a vector space $V$. Do you mean a discrete group of affine transformations which acts on real the affine space  with quotient of finite volume? Or, maybe you mean a generic  orbit of a lattice in an algebraic subgroup $G< GL(V)$?

Comment: A direct way to see a vector space as a linear group is to embed it in a principal diaoginal. This way any vector space, be it real or complex, can be seen as a nilpotent Lie group.

Lattices in nilpotent Lie groups or algebraic groups are very easy to describe. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)#Nilpotent_Lie_groups